# My Azure dev environment always redirects me to an error page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-pipelines

I have an MVC project running locally, and I set-up CI/CD pipelines for it. The issue I am having is that when I go on the server, it always redirects me to an error page. Here is what I am seeing on my end:

[image]

and the URL always adds a `aspxerrorpath` parameter:

[image]

I have custom error pages in place, and here is how my web.config file has them:

```cs
<customErrors mode="On">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/NotFoundError"/>
    <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Error/InternalServerError"/>
</customErrors>
```

and here is my error controller:

```cs
public ActionResult NotFoundError()
  {
    return View("~/Views/Shared/CustomErrors/_Error404.cshtml");
  }

public ActionResult InternalServerError()
  {
    return View("~/Views/Shared/CustomErrors/_Error500.cshtml");
  }
```

Now, this runs fine locally; however, it breaks on the Azure environment. Even when I manually change the url, it gives the error on all the pages I navigate to. The pages show as found in the network tab,`302`, but I still get this error. I have tried the following to fix it but still got the same result:

```cs
public ActionResult NotFoundError(string aspxerrorpath)
 {
   if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(aspxerrorpath))
      return RedirectToAction("~/Views/Shared/CustomErrors/_Error404.cshtml");

   return View("~/Views/Shared/CustomErrors/_Error404.cshtml");
 }

public ActionResult InternalServerError(string aspxerrorpath)
 {
   if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(aspxerrorpath))
      return RedirectToAction("~/Views/Shared/CustomErrors/_Error404.cshtml");

   return View("~/Views/Shared/CustomErrors/_Error500.cshtml");
  }
```

Can someone shed some light on what is going on? How can I fix this error?

Comment: If you need further help, pls let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the connectionString password was changing when it gets deployed on my Azure AppService. I needed to add the `AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings` in my MSBuild Arguments in the build step and set it to false so that it won't tokenize